# Meteor Subscribe and Display Users Count

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to display the number of users in my footer and I would like this number in real time. I think the proper way is to create a publication in the server and to subscribe from the client.

```
// server/publications.js
Meteor.publish("usersCount", function () {
    return Meteor.users.find();
});

// client/main.js
UsersCount = new Meteor.Collection("usersCount");
Meteor.subscribe('usersCount', [], function() {
    console.log('subscribed.');
});

// client/views/layout/footer.js
Template.footer.helpers({
    famecoiners: function(){
        return UsersCount.find().count();
    }
});

// client/views/layout/footer.html
<span>{{famecoiners}} Famecoiners!</span>
```

In the chrome console, we can see the 'subscribed' string from the callback function. The problem is: {{famecoiners}} always returns 0 in my template.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Publishing all of the users will work, but it isn't practical. What if you have 10,000 users? What you really want to do is create a client side collection that holds only one item representing the count. If you look at the second example in the [Publish and subscribe](http://docs.meteor.com/#publishandsubscribe) section of the docs, you'll see something that does this. I'll present a complete working example below:

```
$ meteor create test
$ cd test
$ rm test.*
$ mkdir server client
$ meteor remove autopublish
$ meteor add coffeescript
```

#### client/client.coffee

```
# Create a client-side subscription for the count of users.
UsersCount = new Meteor.Collection 'users-count'

Meteor.subscribe 'usersCount'

Meteor.startup ->
  Meteor.setInterval (->
    # To show something working, read the users count every second.
    uc = UsersCount.findOne()
    console.log uc.count or 0
  ), 1000
```

#### server/server.coffee

```
# Create a 'Users' group for this demo instead of using accounts-password.
Users = new Meteor.Collection 'users'

Meteor.publish 'usersCount', ->
  count = 0 # the count of all users
  initializing = true # true only when we first start
  handle = Users.find().observeChanges
    added: =>
      count++ # Increment the count when users are added.
      @changed 'users-count', 1, {count} unless initializing
    removed: =>
      count-- # Decrement the count when users are removed.
      @changed 'users-count', 1, {count}

  initializing = false

  # Call added now that we are done initializing. Use the id of 1 since
  # there is only ever one object in the collection.
  @added 'users-count', 1, {count}
  # Let the client know that the subscription is ready.
  @ready()

  # Stop the handle when the user disconnects or stops the subscription.
  # This is really important or you will get a memory leak.
  @onStop ->
    handle.stop()

Meteor.startup ->
  # To show something working, insert a new user ever 0.5 seconds.
  Meteor.setInterval (-> Users.insert {}), 500
```

Sorry if you don't like the CoffeeScript - I wanted the code to be compact.

```
$ meteor start
```

If you open the console you will see the user count increase. For fun you can open the mongo shell and run `db.users.remove();` and watch it reset.

Comment: Thank you David, you made me understand a lot of stuff. :)

Comment: Here is a live example for the above code in [meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/DauJz3MDzx5SMzc98). just uncomment `Meteor.setInterval (-> Users.insert {}), 1000` and remove `Users.remove({})` from `server/app.coffee`

Comment: Shame this answer is in coffescript. Can we get an example in the actual language, by any chance?

Comment: Is this still the only way to do this? Is there an updated version to achieve this on newer versions of meteor? Is there a way to do this in javascript/jquery and blaze?

Comment: @weinde see the other answers below. I'd recommend using a package like [publish-counts](https://atmospherejs.com/tmeasday/publish-counts).

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
Template.footer.usercount = function () {
  return Meteor.users.find().count();
};


<template name="footer">
  {{usercount}}
<template>
```

Comment: Thanks Markus! It works too, but David's answer is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

[publish-counts](http://atmospherejs.com/package/publish-counts) mrt package does the job

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the UsersCount new collection stuff, if you're publishing all your users in "usersCount" publication from the "Meteor.users" predefined collection, they'll get subscribed into the same collection on the client.

So basically you want to display "Meteor.users.find().count()" inside your helper.