# Meteor: Publishing all users to the client

Tags: meteor

Why would this not work?:

On both the client and server:

```
AllUsers = new Meteor.Collection('allUsers');
```

On the server only:

```
Meteor.publish('allUsers', function() {
return Meteor.users.find();
});
```

On the client only:

```
Deps.autorun(function(){
Meteor.subscribe("allUsers");
});
```

After I start up this app, `AllUsers.find().count()` is 0 but doing `db.users.find().count()` in the terminal gives the correct number (3).  Even after I add a new user in the browser (using the standard `ui-accounts` package form), which should certainly cause the users collection to change, I still have no documents in my `AllUsers` collection.  I'm beating my head against the wall trying to solve this!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Meteor collections defined on the server have a 1:1 relationship with collections in the database. You don't have a collection in the DB called `'allusers'`, so that definition doesn't make sense. It seems like you are confusing the notion of a database collection and a published result set.

When you add the accounts package to your project, meteor defines the `Meteor.users` collection for you on both the client and the server, so you don't need to do that again. Your code looks fine - just remove the `new Meteor.Collection` and access the users via `Meteor.users.find`.

---

### Collection Definitions Explained

#### Collection created for you by a package

- example: `Meteor.users` is created by the `accounts` package
- notes: The collection in the DB is `db.users`. You can make this collection look like the others you define by doing something like `Users = Meteor.users`, and later calling `Users.find()` instead of `Meteor.users.find()`.

#### Collections defined on both the client and the server

- example: `new Meteor.Collection('rooms')`
- notes: In most projects, this is what you do nearly all of the time. The string `'rooms'` is the name of the collection in the database (`db.rooms`). Documents can be published from the server to the client.

#### Collections defined on the client but not on the server

- example: `new Meteor.Collection('userCount')`
- notes: The server can write to the client collection, but it is not used to sync data to the DB. The typical use case is to inform the client with size or other metadata about another collection. Here the string `'userCount'` does not correspond to the name of a DB collection, but instead is simply an identifier agreed upon by the client and server.
- see also: [How To: Publish to a Client Only Collection](https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/4iCcqw8vPCyCWmiuT) and [Meteor Subscribe and Display Users Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20502638/meteor-subscribe-and-display-users-count/20503982#20503982)

#### Unmanaged local collection defined on the client

- example: `new Meteor.Collection(null)`
- notes: These are defined when the client wants to have collection semantics, but doesn't want to use the collection to communicate with the server. A typical use case would be a demo application, where the user can play with an interface but only alter the data inside her own browser.

Comment: That worked!  And you're right, I am confusing the 2 things -- after much time working with the Meteor book and studying the docs, I'm still unclear about that parameter that you supply to 'new Meteor.Collection()'.  I understand how to use it in certain cases, but not what it is exactly.  It's the name of the collection?  So why do you need a variable name and a string name for a collection?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's probably worthy of a separate question but I went ahead and appended a full write up on collection definitions. If you found this answer helpful, please consider marking it as [accecpted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: That info on collection definitions is EXTREMELY helpful.  As was your link to the "how to accept answers" info.  I am just now seeing this post.

Comment: Hi david. does it imply that console.log("count: "+ Meteor.users.find().count()); inclient will work without any subscribes? I did a quick test and nothing comes up. There are users obviously in db. btw thanks for the guide. good one.

Comment: Did you turn off autopublish?  If not, the users should be there.

Comment: @JimmyMGLim I'm glad it was helpful. :) With `autopublish` off, only the current user (if you are logged in) is published to the client by default. You will need to subscribe for other users in order to get a count on the client.