# meteor subscription/Publish + helper best practice

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I have an app where I want to display a counter of elements I have in one of the collection.
To do so I use a helper that I call in my HTML file `{{nbPosts}}`

```
UI.registerHelper('nbPosts', function () {
return Posts.find().count();
});
```

But to display it I need to subscribe to the whole `Posts` collection.
It does not seem right to me, any suggestion to do that in a better way without sending the whole collection ?

Thanks,

Comment: You can publish just the count, exactly as I did in the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20502638/meteor-subscribe-and-display-users-count/) about users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether you need this to update the data reactively (which I think is not the best idea), or not. If reactivity is not important you can just use a server method, so

```
Meteor.methods({
  'nbPosts': function () {
    return Posts.find().count();
  },
});
```

If you need reactivity you can implement a custom `publish` method, just like in [this](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish) example. Just keep in mind that this will be a lot more expensive in terms of server usage, and so a much less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to have a collection that just keeps track of the number of posts, and update it whenever a post is inserted or removed.