# Get single value from meteor server to client

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I have a **setup** route in which the first user creates his account. If he already has an account he has to be redirected to the **index** route.

On the serverside i would do it like this:

```
if(Meteor.users.find().count > 0){
  //do stuff
}
```

The users collection isn't published to the client. How can i return a simple true/false from the server to a route definition? I tried with Meteor.call('hasUser' function(result){
  console.log(result);
});

But since call is async on the client i always get 'undefined' in my result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has already been asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20502638/meteor-subscribe-and-display-users-count), however you could also do this with the [publish-counts](https://github.com/percolatestudio/publish-counts) package:

```
$ meteor add tmeasday:publish-counts
```

#### server

```js
Meteor.publish('userCount', function() {
  Counts.publish(this, 'userCount', Meteor.users.find());
});
```

#### client

```js
Meteor.subscribe('userCount');
...
Counts.get('userCount');
```

In addition, it also comes with helpers like:

```
<p>There are {{getPublishedCount 'userCount'}} users</p>
```

Comment: David maybe i just get wrong the question, but he don't want to ensure that the user have an existing account to redirect to the `index` route?

Comment: I have reread this a couple of times and now I'm not sure what is being asked. I'll add a comment for clarification.